# Trying to get the image information using OMR in C#.Net,Error at OmrTemplate

Tags: c#, aspose

Trying to get the image information using OMR in C#.Net, Error at OmrTemplate while build the application. I am trying to get the information like marked and unmarked radiobuttons from image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.OMR only supports .amr document as input format. If you are providing a valid .amr template then it should work. This issue needs investigation. For investigation, sample input OMR template and OMR scanned sheet image is required to reproduce the issue. You may follow the same issue on reported on Aspose. support forum.

https://forum.aspose.com/t/omrtemplate-load-will-be-accept-only-amr-formate/170032

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Can we able to convert from .txt format to .amr format?

Comment: No, you can not convert/import .txt formt to .amr format.